# Is it a correct expression to use "impressed upon" this way?

Tags: verbs

I would like to know if it is correct to use the word "impressed" in this way by saying that someone is impressed upon by daily pressure?

Edit: Not in the sense of being convinced but to be negatively impacted or affected.

Thank you.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be used that way. I'm not sure what is wrong with being affected by daily pressure, if that's what you're trying to say. Specifically how they are affected is even better.

Comment: I was trying to emphasize a greater degree of being affected. Not sure but I guess I wondered if it wouldn't be alright because according to the dictionary tr.v. 
1.  To affect strongly, often favorably

2.  To produce or attempt to produce a vivid impression or image of: a scene that impressed itself on her memory

3.  To mark or stamp with pressure: impressed the wax with a design.

4.  To apply with pressure; press: impressed the stamp onto the wax.

Comment: That's all good. You should edit all that information into your question, then perhaps it will not only stay opened, but might get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

That strikes me as a bit awkward. But the word phrase "impress upon" is a synonym of `convince` so I don't think there's anything wrong with your useage.

Comment: Actually it's not really used in the sense of convince but to be affected.

Comment: @Gaia, I'm not sure what you mean. How would you decipher its meaning from the phrase "It's imperative that we impress upon congress that that its urgent that they act on Climate Change."  Or would you take issue with my usage here? Other synonyms are `persist`, `persevere`, and `repeat` and `pound away`. Maybe you're just not familiar with this useage? (I believe it's actually the most common!)

Comment: I mean I'm not trying to use it in that way.